# Grouping bar plots

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to group two barcharts, but I haven't been successful so far...
I followed this [example](http://www.stattler.com/article/some-useful-bar-plots-using-r), but the output is not as desired. The bars are one behind the other instead of next to each other.

[image: barchars ungrouped]

Here's the line of code I use:

```
  barplot(as.matrix(counts),xaxt='n', col=c("white","blue"), ylim=c(0.1,1300), axes=FALSE,  beside=T, space = 1.4, mar=c(5,5,5,5))
```

When I try this...

```
> barplot(as.matrix(counts), beside = TRUE)
> barplot(as.matrix(counts), beside = TRUE, space = c(0, 1.4))
```

... I get this plot:

[image]

And this is my data frame, in case that causes the problem:

```
> counts
     V1  V2
1    26  50
2    50  86
3    86  50
4    50  50
5    50  50
6    50 100
7   100 150
8   150 350
9   350  50
10   50  28
11   28 300
12  300 250
13  250 300
14  300 250
15  250 300
16  300 500
17  500 400
18  400   0
19  600   0
20  500   0
21 1250   0

> dput(counts)
structure(list(V1 = c(26, 50, 86, 50, 50, 50, 100, 150, 350, 
50, 28, 300, 250, 300, 250, 300, 500, 400, 600, 500, 1250), V2 = c(50, 
86, 50, 50, 50, 100, 150, 350, 50, 28, 300, 250, 300, 250, 300, 
500, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, to make your question much easier to answer try to post the output of `dput(counts)` and in such scenarios the image of the chart you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you only provide one `space` value. From `?barplot`: " If height is a matrix and beside is TRUE, space may be specified by two numbers, where the first is the space between bars in the same group, and the second the space between the groups. If not given explicitly, it defaults to c(0,1) if height is a matrix and beside is TRUE".

Try this:

```
barplot(as.matrix(counts), beside = TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(counts), beside = TRUE, space = c(0, 1.4))
```

**Update following comments**
Given that you seem to want bars grouped by row, rather than column (referring to the original data), you need to transpose your matrix to a 'wide' format. In `barplot` each *column* of the input matrix corresponds to a group of bars, and each *row* to different bars within groups. As your original data was organized, the two columns V1 and V2 represented the groups. Thus the plot resulting from my script above have two groups with 21 bars each. After transposing, you will get a plot with 21 groups with two bars each.

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(counts)), beside = TRUE)
```

[image]

I add a `ggplot` example for comparison. In `ggplot` the data should be a data frame in a long format. Thus, first we need to 'melt' the data. Here I use the `melt` function from package `reshape2`. You find several nice `ggplot` examples [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/).

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df <- melt(counts)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = as.factor(Var1), y = value, fill = Var2)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but the result was that I get all bars from V1 grouped together and next to this all bars from V2, also grouped together.